# Generate a limited list of AMI in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

While creating an instance in EC2 using JAVA SDK, is it possible to get the user to select an AMI Instance out of a limited list? Is there an API to display a set of AMIs in EC2??

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is. You want to retrieve a list of AMIs depending on your search criteria.

I am not a java guy. But this functionality is available in :

1. [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html)
2. [AWS Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/ImageCollection.html)

The closest I found for AWS JAVA SDK is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeImagesResult.html).

There are AWS APIs available. So just figure out a JAVA way of doing it.